# Nginx config for serving snapshots to the Google bot

Tags: angularjs, nginx, snapshot

I have an AngularJS app which I'd like to get indexed properly on Google.

I wrote a client that scrapes the sites for links and then downloads the pages with Phantomjs making snapshots. This all works fine. What I'm having a problem with is serving those snapshots to the Google bot.

For some reason, the Google bot appends `?_escaped_fragment=` to my URLs. As an example, `http://me.com/about` gets changed to `http://me.com/about?_escaped_fragment=`. I've verified this in the access logs.

I'm trying to catch this request and serve the Google bot the snapshot with this config:

```
location / {
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=") {
        rewrite ^ /snapshots/$1;
    }
}
```

However, requesting this URL: `http://me.com/about?_escaped_fragment=` always results in a 404. Same with the other pages.

The snapshots are stored in `/snapshots`, relative to the root of the website. They're named after their pages, following directory structure, so `http://me.com/business/register` has a snapshot in `/snapshots/business/register.html`.

What can I do to get these snapshots to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first let me explain why google uses `?_escaped_fragment_`, This is used for websites that rely on ajax, and mark their page with hashes, like for example if you have `http://example.com/gallery/#!image1` and each time the user changes to the next image you update the hash to `image2`, `image3`, but if the user goes directly to `http://example.com/gallery/#!image50` your javascript uses that hash to load the 50th image directly instead of image1 ( servers can't see the hash part, only javascript can ).
So google uses this `_excaped_fragment_` to tell the server which page it's trying to cache.

For more explanation use this [link](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)

As for why you get a 404 error, I think because you used a `$1` without using a capturing block, The right rule would be something like this

```
location / {
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=(.*)") {
        rewrite ^ /snapshots/$1;
    }
}
```

But I don't think this will fix your problem, because according to your example, you didn't use hashes, you used the uri of the page, so i would rewrite the rule to something like this

```
location / {
    # try snapshot, if not found try direct file.
    try_files snapshots$request_uri.html $uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have in nginx and it is working fine, you might need to add a special one for index.html (i.e. when accessing the root of your website)

```
if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=/(.+)/?") {
    set $path $1;
    rewrite ^ /snapshots/$path.html;
    break;
}  

location /snapshots/ {
internal;
    alias /var/www/snapshots/;
}
```

So http://me.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/about will access /var/www/snaphots/about.html

Don't forget this meta tag as well in your page if you use html pushstate instead of hashbangs:

```
meta(name="fragment", content="!")
```